# Using ajax with my JavaScript to store a value while handling events?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, struts

I have a jsp, that contains a `<button>` with an `onclick` event and a list of `<input type="checkbox"/>`s that are being handled with my AjaxScript.js (also mentioned in the next paragraph). I ultimately want to use the Java Bean to call a method that'll handle the functionality while processing the event asychronously.

My solution at this point is to store a list var in my js that I refer to, when the buttons `onclick` is called. The trouble I'm having is in my JSP, where should/can I call the Java method from with a SessionBean variable correctly? Also, if I use the `addEventListener` to handle the `onclick`, how do I get it with the load correctly so it is only handling with the checkbox 'on' click and 'off' click with a very interactive page?

Comment: Are you using any framework or plain JSP + Servlets?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the problem, you have a list of `<input type="checkbox">` (probably with the same name) and want to execute an ajax call when one of them is checked/unchecked and another ajax call when submitting your form with your `<button>` (or `<input type="submit">`), right?

Comment: Struts is not plain JSP + Servlets though

Comment: I'm new to Struts. Maybe that's my problem because to plainly state the problem I'd like to call a Java function from an html object that takes Javascript to handle the event.  I don't know how to get my jsp to see the function in Java. @Luiggi you are completly correct except it's not a "Submit" button it is going to change a value in my db with the need to access Java code to do that.

Comment: Remember: Java is on the server, Javascript is on the client.

Comment: I realize that that is why I'm asking becuase the usual way that I call my Java from a jsp doesn't work.  I need it on an Ajax event. You'd think that a server page could communicate with a simple formula but this one is proving a challenge.